# Ignore base class / interfaces completely in entity framework 5 code first

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-5

I have the following entity class:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("User")]
public class User: UserBase, IPersistCustom<Entity> { ... }
```

Depending on the type of hierarchy mapping you use, EF will generate either a descriptor column or split tables. Is there a way to have EF completely ignore the fact that this class inherits from something or implements an interface?

I don't mean just ignoring base class properties.

Comment: what do mean by ignore... what should happen ?

Comment: If you don't want or can't make base class abstract [there is a better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762308/1718832)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark your base class(es) as abstract and use table per concrete type approach this may work. Something like;

```
context.Entity<User>().Map(p =>
        {
            p.MapInheritedProperties();
            p.ToTable("Users");
        });
```

refer to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this.... 
fluent API option

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<XYZ>().Ignore(p => p.PropertyName);
```